# How to get Client IP address in Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, client-server

I have define a Spring bean.

```
<beans>
  <bean id="remoteService" class="edu.wustl.catissuecore.CaTissueApplictionServicImpl" />
</beans>
```

Is there any way to get the IP address of client in this class? Similarly as available in the servlet `request.getRemoteAddr()`;

Comment: 1.) Is this a webapp or just some random Spring app? 
2.) It's great that edu.wustl.catissuecore.CaTissueApplictionServicImpl (or gov.nih.nci.system.comm.server.ApplicationServiceServerImpl?) *doesn't* implement AbstractController... but what *does* it implement?  If it's not a controller itself, is there a Controller 'above' this that can pass this into this class?
3.) The Spring configuration for the class was already posted in the main question - you need to post code, or at least describe the inheritance hierarchy and what other beans your class interacts with.

Answer (score 20):

The simplest (and ugliest) approach is to use `RequestContextHolder`:

```
  String remoteAddress = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
       .getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

Without knowing more about your bean and how it's wired up, that's the best I can suggest.  If your bean is a controller (either subclassing `AbstractController` or being annotated with `@Controller`) then it should be able to get direct access to the request object.

Comment: No my bean is not inheriting AbstarctController. The bean is :

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
    "http://www.springframework.org     
    /dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
    <beans>
      <bean id="remoteService"       class="gov.nih.nci.system.comm.server.ApplicationServiceServerImpl" />
    </beans>
But i am not getting RequestContextHolder in my classpath. I am using spring 1.2.7

Comment: I'm running my code on localhost and later on server side. Server side its working perfectly. But localhost is return `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` and even using `getLocalAddr()`

Comment: "it should be able to get direct access to the request object" -- what does this mean?

Answer (score 8):

The best way to get client ip is to loop through the headers

```
   private static final String[] IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES = {
        "X-Forwarded-For",
        "Proxy-Client-IP",
        "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
        "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
        "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
        "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
        "HTTP_FORWARDED",
        "HTTP_VIA",
        "REMOTE_ADDR" };

public static String getClientIpAddress(HttpServletRequest request) {
    for (String header : IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES) {
        String ip = request.getHeader(header);
        if (ip != null && ip.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            return ip;
        }
    }
    return request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Construct this:

```
@Autowired(required = true)
private HttpServletRequest  request;
```

and use like this:

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

Comment: This does not work for beans in general: ERROR No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.